# How Can I implement in OOP?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

```
// A is the core class

class A{
   public $lang;
   function sayhi($name){echo "Hi".$name;}
   function speak(){echo "Can Speak".$this->lang;}
}

class B {

  function TODO(){
       echo  " Go to work ";
  }
}
```

I DID for now like this:

```
class C extends B {

    function TODO(){
    //more implement here 

    $a = new A();// here I created an instance.
        // do  any  actions for A
    $a->sayhi("Newbie");
    }

}
```

BUT I  want to class B have all the construct  of class A?

so when I DO on  class C (just something like this)

```
class C extends B {

    function TODO(){
    //more implement here 
     // I wish I can 
       sayhi("Newbie");
    }

}
```

Anybody could tell me how can implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A{
   public $lang;
   function sayhi($name){echo "Hi".$name;}    //here you missed a semicolon
   function speak(){echo "Can Speak".$this->lang;}
}

class B extends A {

  function TODO(){
      echo  " Go to work ";
  }
}

class C extends B {

    function TODO(){
        $this->sayhi("Newbie");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

don't know php that good, but are you searching for this...

```
class A {
}

class B extends A{
}

class C extends B{
}
```

or did i miss something?